# Reset Yosemite to default

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, osx-yosemite-beta

I installed Yosemite, and I would like to reset it to default settings and apps. I don't want to downgrade to Mavericks. Is there any other way than installing clean Mavericks and then upgrade back to Yosemite?

Answer (score 0):

You've done a time machine backup? Then maybe you can make a bootable usb installer.
Have a look at: http://mac-how-to.wonderhowto.com/how-to/create-bootable-install-usb-drive-mac-os-x-10-10-yosemite-0155306/

Comment: Welcome to SO! It is better when you add some info in yout post, instead of providing just a link, because the link might become rotten and your answer no more valid.